# Gap between ons-toolbar and statusbar iOS

Tags: cordova, onsen-ui, onsen-ui2

I am using the onsenUI framework in combination with Cordova in order to create a hybrid application.

For some reason I  observe a gap between the toolbar (text) and the iOS statusbar (iPhone 6s, iOS 11) which is larger then should, see the link for an example. [example of toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hb4Zn.png)

To troubleshoot this issue and to be sure the issue in not caused by my own code I took the code of the very simple example of the toolbar reference at https://onsen.io/v2/api/js/ons-toolbar.html to see what happened on the same iPhone (no own css file used) and the same behaviour is observed.

I am using Cordova to build the App and used the basis settings for the config.xml which are part of the standard Cordova app template. I am applying version 2.8.2 of Onsen, also tried the CDN version. I am using a real iPhone for testing build via XCode.

To confirm it’s not Cordova, I also used plain HTML and also a kitchensick from Framework7 and for both no gap was observed with the same Cordova setup, so something is related with the Onsen setup.

The gap is not shown while running the app in a browser.

Do anyhow has the same behavior and/or an idea what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add `viewport-fit=cover` to the viewport `meta` tag of your index.html

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, viewport-fit=cover">
```

Comment: Hi jcesarmobile, yes this indeed removed the gap. Thanks, that's a useful fix. Interesting item though, I wonder why it is suddenly needed specifically for onsen and e.g. not for plain html or a framework like Framework7. Something must have changed in the onsen framework, maybe related to iPhone X compatibility. There is only one thingy, after the 'splash screen'. I seem to notice a small black bar at the bottom for a fraction of a second before the whole screen fills ... must be the pre-cover state. Guess setting a overall background color matching the app color will hide this .

Comment: This is needed on all apps targeting iOS 11. Framework7 might have added it already to their templates. If you create a Cordova app you will see the same problem there.

Comment: I figured out that using `ons.disableAutoStatusBarFill()` also solves the issue. In relation to `viewport-fit=cover`, this feature works, but it shifts the view up and leaves a gap at the bottom. So I removed the viewport setting for now. Next challenge is to make it all work for iPhone X too as `ons.disableAutoStatusBarFill()`  won't fit for that device and requires probably the viewport solution ... well that is another (stackoverflow) topic.