# 20px margin at the top of mobile screen

Tags: onsen-ui

As you can see below, there is a different at the top of the screen.

(live app) this one is ok no, gap...

[image: ok, no gap]

(test app) this one is not ok, has 20px gap...

[image: not ok, has 20px gap]

So surely I cannot update my app if this problem wont go away. I am using OnsenUI here. The code is still the same, just the environment is new. I don't know if that has influence.

Previously I built with IntelXDK as IDE. All is well. Since IntelXDK is obsolete, now I just running test on a browser using command `cordova run browser`.

All is well, except when I test the code on my iPhone device.

Please shade some lights, thanks.

Comment: Ref: [Gap between ons-toolbar and statusbar iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47517077/2633772)